# Nested Bootstrap Tooltip divs Toggles Parent div's Tooltip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

- I have 2 nested `<div>`s, both with `tooltip()`.
- When I hover over the
  inner `<div>`, the outer `<div>` also shows it's tooltip.
- I tried to work around this by setting the inner `<div>`'s title
  to an empty string on `:hover`.

```js
$(inner).hover({
  $(outer).attr('title','');
},{
  $(outer).attr('title','original title');
});
```

I created a codepen [example](http://codepen.io/warkentien2/pen/LGoGNd)
note: I changed title to 'red' so you can see that the title did indeed change.

1. Why is it that changing the title doesn't change tooltip's content?
2. How do we change the Bootstrap Tooltip's content? (this should be a **stackoverflow** question of it's own)

Answer (score 1):

Answering #1:

By inspecting the elements and watching it change with your JS code, i noticed a attribute on the divs called `data-original-title` which still holds "blue" when you enter green (this is what the tooltip element reads and displays).  By changing your script to

```
 $('#a').attr({"data-original-title": "red"});
```

the blue becomes red.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Also, this appears to answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801805/how-do-i-update-the-content-in-jquery-ui-tooltip-in-realtime

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this attribute. However, it's not imediate. So using ` $('#a').attr({"data-original-title": ""});` as a means to temporary hide the outer `<div>`s tooltip doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I was answering #1 and #2.  I think @BuddhistBeast might have what you want

Comment: edit your answer to explicitly say "answering #1" so I can check it as a valid answer

Comment: Completed as requested.

Comment: I tested out the suggestions and posted a functioning answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether you are currently hovering inside of the inner block

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bIsShown = true;
  $("#b").on('mouseenter', function(){  
      bIsShown = true;

  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
      bIsShown = false;
  })


  $("#a").on('mousemove', function(){  
    if(bIsShown) {
      $(this).data("bs.tooltip").$tip.removeClass("in");
    }
    else {
      $(this).data("bs.tooltip").$tip.addClass("in");
    }
  })
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    animated : 'fade',
    placement : 'bottom',
    container: 'body'});
});
```

Your Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGqXPw

Comment: almost there, must get the outer div (a) to toggle back.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.tooltip('hide')` and `.tooltip('show')`

this was answered in part by @BuddhistBeast, thanks!

```js
$("#b").on('mouseover', function(){   
    $('#a').tooltip('hide');
  }).on('mouseleave', function(){   
    $('#a').tooltip('show');
  });
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    animated : 'true',
    placement : 'bottom',
    container: 'body'});
```